# how to make this div/image using bootstrap grid system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to made this div in bootstrap 3 as shows in image...
I need to display 4 icons/images in one row and another 4 icons in another row in smaller screen/mobile view..i dont know any error in my code..
please help me to make this as shown as in image.

```
<section class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="background-color:#034ea2;">
       <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1 text-center ">
            
            <div class="im1">
                <img src="/images/speaker.png" alt="1" class="siz">

            </div>
            <div class="textt">
                <h6>Sound insultion</h6>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 text-center" >
            <div class="im1">
                <img src="/images/renewable-energy.png" alt="1" class="siz">

            </div>
            <div class="textt">
                <h6>Save energy</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
            <div class="im1">
                <img src="/images/window.png" alt="1" class="siz">

            </div>
            <div class="textt">
                <h6>Prevent Dust Buildup</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
            <div class="im1">
                <img src="/images/stormy.png" alt="1" class="siz">

            </div>
            <div class="textt">
                <h6>Storm Resistant</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
            <div class="im1">
                <img src="/images/hotel-elevator.png" alt="1" class="siz">

            </div>
            <div class="textt">
                <h6>Elegant Looks</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
            <div class="im1">
                <img src="/images/umb.png" alt="1" class="siz">

            </div>
            <div class="textt">
                <h6>Blocks Seepage</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
            <div class="im1">
                <img src="/images/sun.png" alt="1" class="siz">

            </div>
            <div class="textt">
                <h6>Thermal Insulation</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
            <div class="im1">
                <img src="/images/maintenance.png" alt="1" class="siz">

            </div>
            <div class="textt">
                <h6>Low maintenance</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            
        </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

styles

```
.im1{
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  
}

.siz{
  width: 40px;
}
.textt{
  font-size: 15px;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif !important;
  
 
}
```

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkqOg.jpg)

how to make this image using bootstrap grid system...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a code for you. I hope it will help to you.
https://codepen.io/myco27/pen/OvMdGp

```css
img{
  width: 100%;
}
.img1{
  width: calc(100% / 8);
  float:left;
}

@media (max-width: 860px) {
  .img1{
  width: calc(100% / 4);
  float:left;
  }

}
```

```html
<section class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="background-color:#034ea2;">
        <div class="img1 text-center">
            <img src="https://webfoundation.org/docs/2017/03/March-12-Letter.jpg" alt="1">
        </div>
              <div class="img1 text-center">
            <img src="https://webfoundation.org/docs/2017/03/March-12-Letter.jpg" alt="1">
        </div>
              <div class="img1 text-center">
            <img src="https://webfoundation.org/docs/2017/03/March-12-Letter.jpg" alt="1">
        </div>
              <div class="img1 text-center">
            <img src="https://webfoundation.org/docs/2017/03/March-12-Letter.jpg" alt="1">
        </div>
              <div class="img1 text-center">
            <img src="https://webfoundation.org/docs/2017/03/March-12-Letter.jpg" alt="1">
        </div>
              <div class="img1 text-center">
            <img src="https://webfoundation.org/docs/2017/03/March-12-Letter.jpg" alt="1">
        </div>
              <div class="img1 text-center">
            <img src="https://webfoundation.org/docs/2017/03/March-12-Letter.jpg" alt="1">
        </div>
              <div class="img1 text-center">
            <img src="https://webfoundation.org/docs/2017/03/March-12-Letter.jpg" alt="1">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: i need to display 8 icons in one row as shown as in image  for desktop view.i need also display  4 icons/images in one row and another 4 icons in another row in smaller screen/mobile view

Comment: in your desktop view use this width: calc(100% / 8); and your mobile display use this width: calc(100% / 4); .for your display view try to put this in your media query.. if you didn't know how to used that just click this link. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: https://codepen.io/myco27/pen/OvMdGp check this @kasim521 i create image for you.

Comment: great sir ...thank you sir...i have one question..how to adjust left and right distance as shown as in image?the 8 icons are in  the center of div..how to do it?

Comment: add margin if you want to adjust the spacing this is the sample code width: calc(100% / 3 - 1%);

Comment: the image will automatic center because of the "text-center" class in their parent div

Comment: @mycoclaro..sir an error is found.The first image of second raw is moving to middle of the two rows when i resize the page.this process is happened when arriving less than 520px and less than 320px.

Comment: <style>
    .siz{
  width: 40px;
}
.img1{
  width: calc(100% / 8);
  float:left;
  padding-top: 8px;
  border-right: .8px solid white;
  border-bottom: .8px solid white;
  
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .img1{
  width: calc(100% / 4);
  float:left;
  margin-top: 3px;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom:none;
  }

}

</style>

Comment: <section class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="background-color:#034ea2;border:1px solid white;">
                        <div class=" img1 text-center ">
                            <img src="/images/speaker.png" alt="1" class="siz">
                            <h6 class="textt" >Sound insultion</h6>  
                        </div>
                        <div class=" img1 text-center">
                            <img src="/images/renewable-energy.png" alt="1" class="siz">
                            <h6 class="textt">Save energy</h6>  
                        </div>

Comment: `<div class=" img1 text-center">
                            <img src="/images/hotel-elevator.png" alt="1" class="siz">
                            <h6 class="textt">Elegant Looks</h6>   
                        </div>`

Answer (score 0):

First bootstrap runs in a 12 grid sysytem that is defined or can be broken down into 2,3, or 4 segements...basically any divisor of 12. In your case, to get the first four images in a row (in a small device), we split the grid by 3 i.e "`col-md-3`" for each image wrapper and "`col-lg-1`" (for large devices) e.g using a snippet from your code

```
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 text-center">
            <div class="im1">
                <img src="/images/hotel-elevator.png" alt="1" class="siz">

            </div>
            <div class="textt">
                <h6>Elegant Looks</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Then avoid splitting the grid at the main `<div class="col-md-2"></div>` wrapper, simply leave it as `<div class="row justify-content-md-center"></div>`.
This should work just fine. 
NB: The number of images willbe only 8 in this container
For Your CSS is simply modify the following

```
.siz{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: i need to display 8 icons in one row as shown as in image for desktop view.i need also display 4 icons/images in one row and another 4 icons in another row in smaller screen/mobile view

Answer (score 0):

Try This. it has 8 div in 1 row. as shown in image

```
<style>
.main{
background:#034da2;
}
</style>


    <div class="col-md-12 main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                               <img src="image" alt="your image"/>   
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                              <img src="image" alt="your image"/>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                   <img src="image" alt="your image"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                <img src="image" alt="your image"/>    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                 <img src="image" alt="your image"/>     
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                <img src="image" alt="your image"/>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                 <img src="image" alt="your image"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                 <img src="image" alt="your image"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: .how to adjust left and right distance as shown as in image?the 8 icons are in the center of div..how to do it? –